With shield proficiency, do you add your proficiency bonus to your AC?
How does shield proficiency work in D&D 5e?
Do you add the proficiency bonus on to AC (so it is +2 from the shield, and +2 from proficiency, for a total of +4 to AC?

When you have a chance, take the tour and if you have any questions, check the help center.  Happy stacking!

The other question doesn't mention the AC bonus at all, so doesn't answer the confusion in this one.

@SeriousBri If +4 was the point of shield proficiency, that would be mentioned in answers to the question “what’s the point of shield proficiency”. This is a duplicate, as it is clearly covered by the more general question.

@ThomasMarkov I don't know about that. Just because answers to a broader question doesn't take an edge case into account, doesn't mean that this edge case is clarified. I agree that the absence of additional AC in answers it is a pretty good sign that you don't get +4, but that would require future readers to read every single answer in the other thread, trying to find any reference to additional AC from proficiency, only to be left empty handed and have to assume that means it doesn't. IMO, we should not leave people assuming.

@TheLittlePeace Are you saying that having proficiency with a shield while using a shield is an edge case? Because I’d think it would be the primary use case, not an edge case.

@ThomasMarkov I'm saying that proof by absence of evidence is a common fallacy that we should not fall for.

That another answer doesn't say something doesn't mean it is clear that the something doesn't exist. The other question focuses on using a shield far more than anything else. Stop thinking like the person who knows DND and start remembering that the people who have to ask these questions do so because they don't know the answer! You are not protecting the site by stopping people getting answers.

Related, but apparently not a duplicate: What is the point of a shield proficiency?

Also related: Is an equipped shield considered "wearing armor" for gaining benefit from the Defence fighting style?, Is using a shield "wearing armor" or not? Conflicting rulings on Defense Fighting Style and Shield Proficiency, Effects of wearing armor without proficiency

A shield doesn't use your proficiency bonus at all.
A shield gives you a flat +2 AC, whether you're proficient or not (though some magic shields add an extra 1, 2, or 3 in addition). The point of proficiency is to avoid a huge penalty:

Armor proficiency. Anyone can put on a suit of armor or strap a shield to their arm. Only those proficient in the armor's use know how to wear it effectively, however. [...] If you wear armor that you lack proficiency with, you have disadvantage on any ability check, saving throw, or attack roll that involves Strength or Dexterity, and you can't cast spells. (PH p.114)


OK, gone, your instinct is good.

Potentially worth revisiting when the 2024 books come out as I think they have renamed armour and shield proficiency to “training” to avoid exactly this confusion.
